# Fine tuning custom keras model

Tags: keras

I have a keras model which is trained on 5 classes,The final layers of the model look like so

```
dr_steps = Dropout(0.25)(Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(gap_dr))
out_layer = Dense(5, activation = 'softmax')(dr_steps)
model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
```

What I want to do is fine tune this model on an 8 class multilabel problem but I am not sure how to achieve this. This is what I have tried:

```
dr_steps = Dropout(0.25)(Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(gap_dr))
out_layer = Dense(t_y.shape[-1], activation = 'softmax')(dr_steps)
model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
weights_path = 'weights.best.hdf5'
retina_model.load_weights(weights_path)
model.layers.pop()
output = Dense(8, activation = 'sigmoid')(model.layers[-1].output)
model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [output])
loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
model.compile(optimizer = RAdam(), loss = FocalLoss,
                         metrics = ["binary_accuracy",precision, recall,auc])
```

but this will raise an error like this

```
raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 8 and 5. Shapes are [128,8] and [128,5]. for 'Assign_390' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [128,8], [128,5].
```

Any suggestions on how to fine tune this model will be very helpful,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```py
model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
weights_path = 'weights.best.hdf5'
```

this **out_layer** should have the same dimension(5 classes) described inside **weights.best.hdf5**.

So, `t_y.shape[-1]` should be `5` dimensional, *not 8*.